# Get then add checkbox value into variable, if checked

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I found this example:

The Idea is to get the **checked** checkbox **value**, and use it further as avariable:

Maybe this example is not the best, but I only found this one as it is much closer to what I want.

See [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vaKWs/6/)

```
<div id="pakker">
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="39" />test 1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="79" />test 2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="29" />test 3<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="49" />test 4<br/>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var sum = 0;
    $('#pakker :checkbox').click(function() {
        sum = 0;
        $('#pakker :checkbox:checked').each(function(idx, elm) {
            sum += parseInt(elm.value, 10);
        });

        $('#sum').html(sum);

    });
});
</script>
```

1. As you can see it shows values only after mouse click checkbox. How can I make it to get the **checked** checkbox value on Loading page? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vaKWs/31/
2. if more then one checkbox is selected it ADDS the numbers. is it possible to show the valuse like (93, 25, 256 etc) without adding them?
3. Is it possible the result to put into a VARIABLE so that i can use this variable in other functions on the page? For example if $variable { then } esle {...

*** PS *** I am new with php and js. Thank you for understanding!

Comment: Okay, why's this tagged [`PHP`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)?

Comment: I plan to use the variable in php further? :) or it is not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var sum = 0;
$('#pakker :checkbox').click(function() {
    sum = 0;
    $('#pakker :checkbox:checked').each(function(idx, elm) {
        sum += parseInt(elm.value, 10);
    });

    $('#sum').html(sum);

});
$('#pakker :checkbox[checked]').each(function(idx, elm){
sum += parseInt(elm.value, 10);
});
$('#sum').html(sum);
});
```

in HTML:

```
    <input type="checkbox" checked value="39" />test 1<br/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vaKWs/6/

There you go.

Please rate my answer.

that would really help me!!

Comment: added a modification for HTML, please see.

Comment: Thank you! 1 question is answwered.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to give such a direct answer man...you pretty much did the work for him. The purpose of all this is for him to learn and find out on his own :S  I know this is not the place for it but I just needed to say it...nothing personal of course.  Sorry if I offended you

Comment: how about 2 & 3 question?

Comment: Jose - i think you didnt offended anybody, its just you write so much, and u loose so much time. Spend it better on good things. And thank you for your opinion anyway!

Answer (score 0):

1. already answered
2. You use a sum of the values, if you want them as separate text: `sum += parseInt(elm.value, 10) + " "` should do it. This forces a space between keeping them as a text string.
3. The example you have saves them into a variable already. Check out arrays for storing them into individual variables

Hope that helps

Comment: With 3rd I still try to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

Actually @Jose makes a lot of sense to me.
i felt exactly like you before. but with of a lot of learning i manage to create nice sites.
let me help you on 3:

if you assign a varible at the top of the page like that HTML:

```
<script>
myNewVar = new Array();
//... rest of the script
</script>
```

so that variable is available to all scripts around..

Comment: yeah that makes sense. And maybe its a stupid question. But is is possible to use it in php, I mean the variable?

Comment: I am still learning too and it just feels I learn and make more way when hints and clues are given (not the full answer)...but I guess people work differently and this could be the way some people learn better

Comment: @Andrei Sure. but you should learn first more.
what you are talkin about is GET and POST variables that the user send to the server. its very basic.(every system deal with a lot of that)

Comment: You cant directly access js from php (look up server side/client side) you need to submit the value to the page using get or post as mentioned